# Sending commands to Bloomberg terminal using Bloomberg API

Tags: c#, bloomberg

I have the following code to manipulate a Bloomberg terminal, and I want to upgrade this code to use the official Bloomberg API. I have been able to download the API from Bloomberg and run the C# examples on the machine with the Bloomberg Terminal installed.

```
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
            Thread.Sleep(delay);

            SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");
            Thread.Sleep(delay);

            SendKeys.SendWait("IB> " + uuid);
            Thread.Sleep(delay);

            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

I am not able to find an example which is pure around executing commands (automation) on the machine they appear to be more around accessing data.

Is there a way to send commands & arguments via the Bloomberg API to the Bloomberg Terminal?

Comment: I don't think so - the API allows you to query "stuff" from Bloomberg, it's not meant to automate the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bloomberg provide a Terminal Connect SDK which can be dowloaded from the Bloomberg Terminal, type SDK <Enter>. Once installed you will be able to manipulate simple functions in Bloomberg.

For my example above I was able to start Bloomberg IB chat with the following code:

```
BlpApi.Register();
BlpTerminal.RunFunction("IB >122234", "1");
```

However there are some drawbacks with this approach

1. You have to have a strong named assembly and register the key with Bloomberg (this is detailed in the help files provided by the Terminal Connect SDK),
2. There is a licensing cost to using the Terminal Connect SDK.